# issue with scroll on android browser

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have the following html strcture :

```
<div id='container'>
 <div id='page'>

   <div class='header'>
     <h1>Title</h1>
   </div>

   <div class='content'>
     <!-- large text here -->
   </div> 

 </div>
</div>


#container{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#page{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}
.content{
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 overflow-scrolling: touch;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

the content height is dynamic it took the (documentHeight - headerHeight)

this solution works fine on chrome but not on the android browser

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look at the new CSS3 Media Queries, they require a different build of your HTML page, but will be better in creating a responsive website for any device. 
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/